# Post textarea using @Html.ActionLink - ASP.NET MVC 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

I know that this question was answered many times, but since I don't know much about javascript, and this is my first website, I followed the answer in  [this](https://www.quora.com/unanswered/How-can-I-send-scripts-from-ASP-NET-MVC-5-to-the-server-to-compile-Java-code) link. This is my code so far:

```
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Save","SaveClass",new { path2=Model.path,code="xxx"},new { id="save"})</li>
@Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.code, new { id = "code" })
<script>
       $("#save").click(function(evt) {
           var fakedUri = $("#save").attr("href");
           alert($('#code').val());
           var uri = $("#save").attr("href").replace("xxx", $("#code").val());
});
    </script>
```

And this is my controller:

```
public ActionResult SaveClass(string path2,string code)
    {
        modelSC.path = path2;
        modelSC.code = code;
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(Server.MapPath(modelSC.path), code);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The code always saves 'xxx' to the file, and throws:

> The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by
> the static file handler.

How can I get it to work?

Comment: Use a form instead of an ActionLink. This isn't what links are intended for.

Comment: By forms, do you mean @Html.BeginForm()? I used it before and it worked perfectly, but it uses buttons, while here I need links.

Comment: yes. you can make a button look like a link with CSS, if someone has been daft enough to make that a requirement. Technically you don't _need_ a link here, a button will do the same job - they are both ways of making new requests to the server.

Comment: Thank you! it works now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ActionLink` helper generates a link and clicking on that will issue a GET request. Looks like you are trying to send the value of the text area through querystring to the next action method. But GET might not be the best solution to handle that. Querystring has a limit on how much data it can handle (varies for different browsers).

Ideally you should do a form submit, If you do not prefer a button, but want a link to initiate the form submit, that is possible with a little javascript.

```
@using(Html.BeginForm("SaveClass","YourControllerName"))
{
  @Html.TextAreaFor(m=>m.code)
  @Html.HiddenFor(s=>s.path)
  @Html.ActionLink("Save","SaveClass","YourControllerName",null,new { id="save"})

}
```

Now in your javascript, when click on the link, stop the default behavior (the default GET Action) and then submit the form where the clicked link is present. We can use the `closest()` method.

```
$(function(){

  $("#save").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest("form").submit();
  });

})
```

Make sure you use the correct parameter name (matching with the input name)

```
public ActionResult SaveClass(string path,string code)
{
   // to do  : return something
}
```

Comment: It still throws `The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler ` exception. But it stores the input correctly!

Comment: When exactly & where are you getting this message ?

Comment: When I click save, I get this message. But after I reload the page I find that it stored the value correctly.

Comment: are you getting that error when redirecting to the Index action (after saving you are redirecting to index). In that case it would be a problem with Index page. you should be able to see the same message when you directly access that action in browser.

Comment: I don't see it when I access the "Index " action directly, but yes, it looks like I'm getting it when I redirect from "SaveClass" or any other views.